# Some indexes failed to download

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu, kde, muon-package-manager

When trying to run `sudo apt-get update` I'm getting an error which says `Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`, I've tried all the solutions mentioned for this but none seems to work, Here are some things that I've tried.

- `sudo apt-get clean` then `sudo apt-get update`.
- `sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing`.
- Have also tried deleting the list files but it doesn't work either.and I'm running kubuntu 20.4, Can  Someone please help me with this??

Comment: Please add complete text output of `sudo apt-get update` command to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1254294/edit).

Comment: @N0rbert The problem was fixed by changing the software source to main server.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone couldn't get their package manager working by running the commands mentioned in the question, Then they can try changing the server to `Main Server` in their software sources (Note :- The following command is for kubuntu and might differ for any other distros). Open up the terminal and run the command `sudo software-properties-kde`. This will open up the software sources panel then from their you can just change the server to `Main Server`.